# How does the Starkiller death beam move so quickly?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In Star Wars: The Force Awakens, the Starkiller is demonstrated. However, just as quickly as Kylo Ren and company gives the order, 3-4 planets.

The Starkiller appears to defy the theory of relativity and the laws of physics. How is this possible? If we were to ever have a weapon of this magnitude and decided to destroy a plan within our galaxy, we can expect the trajectory to take quite a few light years. Why is it that as soon as the Starkiller fires, the planets were almost instantaneously destroyed as opposed to the trajectory taking x amount of light years to hit its target?

Comment: Are you trying to use [light-years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-year) as a measure of time?

Comment: Yeah but i guess the other post you provided seems to offer an explanation..

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Why not? That's the first idea about the Kessel Run, yes?